# Is there any guide about VMSS Azure scheduled scaling

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-vm-scale-set, runbook

I have some problem.
Is it possible to set up vmss (Virtual Machine Scale Set) scaling with specified schedule? If yes, please give me the path to solution guide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-advanced-autoscale-virtual-machine-scale-sets), basically what you need to do is create a Scale Set with some schedule, go into [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) and modify it to suit your needs:

```
{
    "name": "Weekday_Morning_Hours_Scale",
    "capacity": {
    "minimum": "4",
    "maximum": "12",
    "default": "4"
    },
    "rules": [],
    "recurrence": {
    "frequency": "Week",
    "schedule": {
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time",
        "days": [
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday"
        ],
        "hours": [
        6
        ],
        "minutes": [
        0
        ]
    }
    }
},
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you! But I have some problems to solve. Is it possible to scale my scale set with specified schedule via Runbook?

Comment: yes, but whats the point, you can just create a schedule for that? @MityaKuznetsov